# How to enable Wifi direct on the Raspberry Pi using the TL-WN721N wireless Adapter (Noob instruction)

Tags: raspbian, android, wifi-direct

I was looking to find noob instructions on how to connect to the Raspberry Pi using [Wifi Direct](http://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-direct) from either a phone or another computer. I tried a few instruction but they are aimed for more advanced users (eg: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GPv8TfZqe4) so any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I know it might be hard to connect a computer to a Raspberry Pi using Wifi direct but I was hoping for decent instructions so that I could at least connect through to an android device like this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jai2TSk795g)

Comment: How far along are you? Do you have the adapter recognized by the RPi yet?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I guess your question is very similar to this one
[Connect to Raspberry PI 3 over Wi-Fi direct](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45451/connect-to-raspberry-pi-3-over-wi-fi-direct)

but instead of a phone you are using your laptop. Just do these steps through the terminal on the raspberry pi

install wpasupplicant

```
1. Open terminal 
2. apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

Edit the Config file

```
sudo nano etc/wpa_supplicant/p2p.conf
```

Copy the following into it

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant 
update_config=1

ap_scan=1
device_name=RPi_3
device_type=1-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
driver_param=p2p_device=1
p2p_go_intent=10
p2p_go_ht40=1
```

Then to Start it just type

`sudo wpa_supplicant -B -dd -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

If you want to stop it, just terminate it with

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 terminate
```

Comment: Are you suggesting doing these steps on the Rpi? How about the laptop?

Comment: these are done on the raspeberry pi to enable wifi Direct. Then to connect to the wifi-direct of the pi using your laptop it should appear as a normal wifi option.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the **official** Raspberry Pi tutorial here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Cheers!

Comment: That wasn't the question. The OP wanted to use Wifi Direct to connect without a network.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to use [nmcli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line).
That is a network-manager command line tool.

See the list of available connections:

```
nmcli d wifi list
```

To connect to the wifi:

```
nmcli d wifi connect <WiFiSSID> password <WiFiPassword> iface <WifiInterface>
```

[additional info in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Seems like a useful tool, but that wasn't the question. The OP wanted to use Wifi Direct to connect without a network.