# Setting up a WiFi-direct connection using pi3+arch linux arm and Android

Tags: pi-3, archlinux, wifi-direct

I want to set up a wifi direct connection between my phone and my pi3.
I followed this post 
[Connect to Raspberry PI 3 over Wi-Fi direct](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45451/connect-to-raspberry-pi-3-over-wi-fi-direct)
hoping i would be at least able to see my phones open wifi direct connection, but the wpa_supplicant wont start, reporting either

```
Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlan0 flags: No such device
```

or

```
Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlan0: -16 (Device or resource busy)
```

iw list tells me

```
* P2P-client     
* P2P-GO     
* P2P-device
```

are all available, which is of no suprise since most tech spec descriptions of the pi3 list wifi direct capabilities...

in my search for answers I stumbled across some people saying "it's a wpa_supplicant 2.5 bug, downgrade your wpa_supplicant" but im no able to find a arm version of the wpa_supplicant 2.3 anywhere. I did find some 2.3 packages in the Archlinux Rollback Machine, but pacman dismissed those as "wrong architecture".

Anyone got any ideas how to solve this?

ps: i got raspbian installed on another sd-card, almost the same problem

---

**edit:**
Raspbian got wpa_supplicant 2.3, I started the wpa_supplicant with these configs

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
device_name=PI
update_config=1
```

(just like Van Coding in his post)
The wpa_supplicant started, but p2p_find and p2p_listen wouldn't produce any results at all. Extended debug informations revealed

```
nl80211: Do not indicate P2P_DEVICE support (p2p_device=1 driver param not specified)
```

so I added

```
driver_param=p2p_device=1
```

to the params, which, in turn, lead to

```
Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlan0: -16 (Device or resource busy)
nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlan0
P2P: Failed to create P2P Device interface
```

again, Indicating some other problem than a faulty wpa_supplicant release

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. Then I found that a `wpa_supplicant` process was already started at boot time to connect to public WIFI. This is why there is the "resource busy" error message. I did a `sudo killall wpa_supplicant` and retried my `wpa_supplicant` command, and it worked. Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: For some reason, this didn't quite work for me. It immediately respawned the process. I had to `systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service`, then run the `wpa_supplicant` command again. It worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

I also have alarm on the RPi3 and followed [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#netctl) to establish a wireless connection. I used netctl (installed by default on alarm), but there's a lot of other options.

Then I followed the [netctl wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Wireless_.28WPA-PSK.29) instructions.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, What I did was download the source for wpa_supplicant from their website [wpa_supplicant source for arm](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/wpa_supplicant.html). they have instructions on that site for building it as well. making it failed a bunch of times for me because I was missing dependencies like libssl-dev, libncurses-dev and libreadline-dev so after I got that squared away the errors went away, but it still wouldn't connect until after I rebooted, then everything worked.