# How to connect to Pi 3 using WiFi Direct on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi-direct

How can I set up my Pi 3, which is running Rasbian, so that I can connect to the internal WiFi using WiFi Direct?

Comment: Have you seen this questions and answer on SE? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45451/connect-to-raspberry-pi-3-over-wi-fi-direct does this help?  If not could you specify where the answer doesn't solve your issue?

Comment: I have seen that post, however that is based on Arch Linux, which uses wpa supplicant, I would like to use Raspbian.

Comment: The exact same tools are available on Raspbian.  The dupe accepted *answer* actually does not refer to any specific distro at all.