# Connect Pi3 to Windows/Linux via wifi direct?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, windows, wifi-direct

I'm building something that needs to connect to a Pi3 wirelessly but there won't always be a wifi network for them to talk over. So I was hoping to use wifi direct to get them to talk directly.

So far i've been having problems finding a library that will run on both Windows 10 and Raspbian. I looked at this [question about connecting Android and Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/45451/49462) but he's using Arch Linux on his Pi (which I will install if there is no Raspbian alternative). That question is also based around Android for the connecting device, I'm unsure how to actually get Windows to search for a Wifi Direct network
and then to connect to it since Android appears to just connect without much extra setup.

Ideally What I need is a library that will work on **Windows and Linux** that can be used in **C++ or C#** for handling all the Wifi Direct stuff...

Answer (score 2):

I have been recently researching on my project just similar with yours. I'll give my solution below.

1. first of all, you shall have WiFi module that support WiFi-Direct used by desktop linux/windows.
2. in case rpi3 <--> desktop linux, you can connect them via wpa_supplicant with p2p commands.
3. in case rpi3 <--> desktop windows, I recommand windows 10 because it's the only verison that support WiFi-direct and provide API via UWP.

Comment: shame that windows makes you use UWP though there is probably a hacky way around it