# How to connect two PI 3 to each other through ad-hoc connection?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, wireless, communication, wifi-direct

Okay, I am very much a NEWBIE when it comes to these type of connections. So, I searched on this website on how to be able to do this and I came across two promising questions and answers. However, they don't seem to be helping. First, I tried the following question's answer.
[Ad-hoc setup for pi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49660/ad-hoc-setup-in-rpi-3) 
All I see is a tooltip saying the following for both PI 3 but with different ip address. With this setup, I can't make PIs talk to each other. I don't even know if they see each other even though they are supposed to be on the same network SSID (thayanet). I can't even PING from each other.

[image: Wlan0 tooltip]

Then, I tried the second question I found - [Connect to Raspberry PI 3 over Wi-Fi direct](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45451/connect-to-raspberry-pi-3-over-wi-fi-direct)
This question also didn't help me. Once I made the changes wpa_supplicant.conf file, it spit out all sorts of errors such as unsupported drivers, failed to add interface wlan0, etc...

I simply want to setup a Ad-Hoc connection for my two PIs. So, they can communicate with each other. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE** Once I set up ad-hoc on one PI, the other PI sees that network. Now, how do I use this network setup. I try to connect the non-ad-hoc PI to ad-hoc PI and it won't connect.

Comment: You **NEED** to list what **YOU** actually did, not post links to tutorials. There is one obvious issue wlan0 has a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

Comment: @Milliways I did exactly what those answers said. So, if anything that's what I would be listing here. I didn't deviate from those questions' answers in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the `iwconfig` tools on the both your Pis to join to an ad-hoc network.

use the following:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc channel 01 essid my-net
```

You can use your Link-Local addresses to interact with the pis in general.

A smart way to know your local network Pis can be to use:

```
ping -I wlan0 224.0.0.1
```

It is a [Multicast Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) which will give your pings from the Pis which have the same ad-hoc parameters.

This should most definitely give you the `169.254.x.x` address of the Pi within the ad-hoc network.

### Networking upon next boot

In best case use the following in your (both Pis) `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid my-net channel 01
exit 0
```

and add `brcmfmac` in to your `/etc/modules` file for availability of chipset on boot.

For further help I have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/pi_adhoc_script) which can set up Pis (any model 2 or 3) in Ad-Hoc mode with IPv6 Link Local Addresses.

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean to run the identical `sudo iwconfig ...`command on both Raspberry Pis please? Also, can you clarify what the `xx` stand for and where OP is supposed to get the actual values from? Thank you.

Comment: Good point I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Shan-Desai Your answer is great so far. However, once non-ad-hoc PI connects to the ad-hoc pi successfully, I can't ping the ad-hoc PI from the other pi or vice versa. I keep getting Destination not reachable. I did the `ping -I wlan0 mypis-ip` But I see the network green LED on both PIs blinking once every seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the improvements - I have upvoted your answer. There is no mention of how to enable/disable a wifi password or how to set the encryption by the way.

Comment: Sadly that is not what I have figured out as of yet. WPA supplicant and its features are lacking and will research on it soon. About the connectivity you might have to restart your `avahi-daemon` `sudo avahi-daemon -r`

Comment: @Shan-Desai I ran your adhoc script. It executed as expected and I tried to do the same as before. Both of my PIs connected. However, I can't seem to PING from either one. So, how do I test the wifi or adhoc connection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully done it using link-local networking.

Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

Some googling will let you know what needs to be set up. Since there is no DHCP server, each Pi needs a set static address (although it may auto-config and get it's own), and then be configured to access the other Pi via Wifi. I am not sure how to do this, I have only linked mine via Ethernet, but I am sure it's not terribly different.